# JS валидация логина

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть логин форма. Логин проходит валидацию вот так

```
  var loginValue = document.getElementById("loginValue").children[0];

    var valid_email = /^([a-z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/;

    if(loginValue.value!=''&& valid_email.test(loginValue.value)){
       //success action
    }
```

Если в логине в конце логина пользователь введет пробел, то валидация будет не пройдена. Как изменить регулярку, чтобы пробелы в конце и в начале обрезались? Или по-другому лучше как-то можно сделать?

Comment: `input[type=email]` по мне лучше вариант

Comment: Долго объяснять, но это не подходит. Может регулярку изменить можно?

Answer (score 0):

Есть у строк такой метод - [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: Тогда мне придется тримить в двух местах. Нельзя ли регулярку изменить как-то?